# Parsing Tree data file in perl

Tags: perl, tree, csv

I am newbie to Perl. I had a file which contain data in Tree format as shown bellow. I need to parse large data and generate .TSV file from that. Format of file is as

```
A 
|
|--B 
|  |
|  |--C
|     | 
|     |---PQR
|     |---XYZ
|--D
|  |
|  |---LMN
|---XYZ
```

The output that I need is in Tab Separated format.

```
Coloum1     Coloum2     Coloum3     Coloum4 
A           B           C           PQR
A           B           C           XYZ
A           D                       LMN
A                                   XYZ
```

I have written a code which is not working for intermediate node. Here it is B node which does not have leaf node, leaf node that are attached to root node is not properly coming in output. I am reading Input file from command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
open (MYFILE, "<", $ARGV[0]);

my $content = "";
while(<MYFILE>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    $content = $content.$line;
}

my ($root, @block) = split(/\|--(\w)/, $content);

$root =~ s/.*?(\w+).*/$1/is;
my %block = @block;

print "\nColoum1\tColumn2\tColumn3\tColumn4";
foreach my $key( keys %block)
{
    my $content =  $block{$key};
    my (undef, @lines) = split(/\n/, $content);
    foreach my $line (@lines)
    {
        if($line =~ /---(\w+)/is)
        {
            my $val = $1;

            if(defined $val)
            {
                print "\n$root\t$key\t$val";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I got from this is

```
Coloum1     Column2     Column3     Column4
A           D       LMN
A           D       XYZ
A           C       PQR
A           C       XYZ
```

Is something that I am missing in this code. Can you guide me to solve my problem.

Is there any CPAN library that can help me to handle such problem.

Comment: Can you describe the input format in more detail? Why is there no vertical bar at the beginning of the `LMN` line? Is the number of dashes significant (2 - inner node, 3 - leaf)? Why is the vertical bar below B shifted to the right?

Comment: Yes You are right there is vertical bar at beginning of LMN line. And number of dashes signifies (2 -) for inner node and (3 -) for leaf node. its typo mistake for vertical bar. I also modifying my inputs.

Comment: I have the code ready, but cannot post it here as the question is put on hold. Please, try to improve it.

Comment: @choroba : I just modified my question and added the effort that I done to solve the problem, but it is not working. Need your help

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CichAlmpmA

Comment: @choroba thanks a lot. It works like champ. Once again thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 4):

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More tests => 1;

my $input = 'A 
|
|--B 
|  |
|  |--C
|     | 
|     |---PQR
|     |---XYZ
|--D
|  |
|  |---LMN
|---XYZ
';

open my $IN, '<', \$input or die $!;

my @path;
my @output;
my $size = 0;

while (<$IN>) {
    if (!/\|/) {                        # Root.
        @path = [0, /(\S+)/];

    } elsif (/\|(?=-)/g) {              # Capture the position of the last |.

        if ($path[-1][0] == pos) {      # Sibling.
            ($path[-1][1]) = /-+(\S+)/;

        } elsif ( $path[-1][0] < pos) { # Child.
            push @path, [pos, /-+(\S+)/];

        } else {                        # New branch.
            pop @path until $path[-1][0] == pos;
            $path[-1] = [pos, /-+(\S+)/];
        }

        if (/---/) {
            push @output, [ map $_->[1], @path ];
            $size = @path if @path > $size;
        }
    }
}

my $expected = 'Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
A   B   C   PQR
A   B   C   XYZ
A   D       LMN
A           XYZ
';

my $output = join "\t", map "Column$_", 1 .. $size;

for my $row (@output) {
    $output .= "\n";
    $output .= join "\t", @{$row}[0 .. $#{$row} - 1],
                          (q()) x ($size - @$row),
                          $row->[-1];
}
$output .= "\n";

is($output, $expected);
```